# What's the expected behavior of UserInfo.getUIThemeDisplayed()?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, userinfo

Looking for clarification around the `getUIThemeDisplayed()` method. I have simple VF page that displays the value returned by this method from a corresponding controller and a lightning component on the same VF page that also shows the value returned from the method from the same controller.

When in SF classic I'm seeing both the VF page and Lightning Comp returning `Theme3` (SF Classic). So far so good. But when I switch (via the menu) to LEX and go to the VF page, the VF page shows `Theme3` (Classic) and the component returns `Theme4d` (LEX).

**Example VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="ThemeTestController" showHeader="true">

    <apex:includeLightning />
    Theme returned by VisualForce page: {!UIThemeValue}

    <div id="lightning" />

    <script> 
        window.onload = function(){
            $Lightning.use("c:TestApp", function() {

                $Lightning.createComponent("c:ThemeTestCmp",
                {},
                "lightning",
                function(cmp) {
                });
            });
        }
    </script>

</apex:page>
```

[Documentation states](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm) these variables Identify the CSS used to render SF web pages to a user, so if the component utilizing Lightning CSS and the VF still uses classic CSS hence the different values displayed? And if so, why do we see both the VisualForce page and component display `Theme3` when in classic?

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice trailhead [Sharing Visualforce Pages Between Classic and Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_visualforce/units/lex_dev_visualforce_multipurpose_pages) on this to answer your question.

> Use the $User.UITheme and $User.UIThemeDisplayed global variables to determine the current user experience context. You can use these variables in Visualforce expressions to adapt your pages to Lightning Experience, Salesforce Classic, and Salesforce1.
>
> These global variables return a string that uniquely identifies the current user interface context. The possible values for $User.UITheme and $User.UIThemeDisplayed are the same:

- Theme1—Obsolete Salesforce theme
- Theme2—Salesforce Classic 2005 user interface theme
- Theme3—Salesforce Classic 2010 user interface theme
- Theme4d—Modern “Lightning Experience” Salesforce theme
- Theme4t—Salesforce1 mobile Salesforce theme
- PortalDefault—Salesforce Customer Portal theme
- Webstore—Salesforce AppExchange theme

> Question: When in SF classic I'm seeing both the VF page and Lightning Comp returning Theme3 (SF Classic). So far so good. But when I switch (via the menu) to LEX and go to the VF page, the VF page shows Theme3 (Classic) and the component returns Theme4d (LEX).

The difference between the two variables is that `$User.UITheme` returns the look and feel the user is supposed to see, **while `$User.UIThemeDisplayed` returns the look and feel the user actually sees**. For example, a user may have the preference and permissions to see the Lightning Experience look and feel, but **if they are using a browser that doesn’t support that look and feel, for example, older versions of Internet Explorer, $User.UIThemeDisplayed returns a different value**.

***And, here this is happening for you.***

In general, your code should use `$User.UIThemeDisplayed`.
The simplest way to use these theme globals is to use one in a Boolean expression, like `{! $User.UIThemeDisplayed == "Theme3" }`, in the rendered attribute of a component. The component will only display if the page appears in the desired user interface context.

```
// This is an anonymous self-executing function closure thingie,
// like all the cool kids are using these days.
(function(myContext){

    // Deal with possible order-of-execution issues.
    // Don't overwrite ourself if we already exist.
    myContext.ForceUI = myContext.ForceUI || {};

    // Utility methods that make simple string comparisons
    // against a local UserUITheme value. This value is
    // injected from a Visualforce page to allow expression
    // evaluation of the $User.UIThemeDisplayed global.
    myContext.ForceUI.isSalesforceClassic = function() {
        return (this.UserUITheme == 'Theme3');
    }
    myContext.ForceUI.isLightningExperience = function() {
        return (this.UserUITheme == 'Theme4d');
    }
    myContext.ForceUI.isSalesforce1 = function() {
        return (this.UserUITheme == 'Theme4t');
    }
})(this);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm aware of the current documentation. And this doesn't answer the above question: How am I seeing both Theme3 (from the VF page call to controller method) and Theme4d being returned by the lightning component on the same VF page (when calling the same controller method) when in LEX?

Comment: You're talking about, "if they are using a browser that doesn’t support that look and feel, for example, older versions of Internet Explorer, $User.UIThemeDisplayed returns a different value."? This doesn't apply here, I'm using Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit), a browser that very much supports LEX. Not sure how that would answer this at all... I'm not navigating to a VF page two separate times and getting a different result, I'm actually requesting a single VF page once.

Comment: Yes, thats correct, suggest you to change the browser and use latest google chrome to test your functionality

Comment: Also, rather than switching from classic to LEX from the menu, try to log off and login directly in LEX and see the results

Comment: Take a look at the code for my VF page, you can see that I'm displaying the value returned from the method twice on the page. When in LEX I'm getting different values, don't think this is explained at all from current docs.

Comment: Yes, current doc doesn't have this kind of explanations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56674/discussion-between-brand0r-and-santanu-boral).